# How to link a button to another component in an array

Tags: angular

strong text
Hello, I am new to Angular2 and I require some help. I am doing a catalogue app. I have created an array( I think it is one), however I need each item in the array to be linked to another component. I intend to have a link in the Typescript file for each item, then the button in the HTML file will call it. However, I am not sure as to how to do it.

Typescript File:

```js
export class NikeComponent implements OnInit {
 title = 'Nike Catalgoue';
  
  nikeShirts =  [ {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Nike SB x Medicom Dry",
   "description": "Men's T-Shirt",
   "inStock": "$49",
      "image": "../assets/nike_shirt_1.jpg",
   
  },
{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "NikeLab ACG",
   "description": "Men's T-Shirt",
   "inStock": "$109",
     "image": "../assets/nike_shirt_2.jpg"
 },
{
   "id": 3,
   "name": "Nike Futura Icon",
   "description": "Men's T-Shirt",
   "inStock": "$42",
     "image": "../assets/adidas_shirt_3.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 4,
   "name": "Nike SB x Medicom Dry",
   "description": "Men's T-Shirt",
   "inStock": "$49",
      "image": "../assets/nike_shirt_1.jpg",
  
  },
{
   "id": 5 ,
   "name": "NikeLab ACG",
   "description": "Men's T-Shirt",
   "inStock": "$109",
     "image": "../assets/nike_shirt_2.jpg"
 },
{
   "id": 6,
   "name": "Nike Futura Icon",
   "description": "Men's T-Shirt",
   "inStock": "$42",
     "image": "../assets/nike_shirt_3.jpg"
}];
```

HTML file:

```html
<li *ngFor = "let nikeShirt of nikeShirts">
  <img src ={{nikeShirt.image}} height="200" width="250" />
  <h2> {{nikeShirt.name}} </h2>
 <p> <i>{{nikeShirt.description}}</i> </p>
 <p> {{nikeShirt.inStock}} </p>
   <button href="/home" class="btn">Review</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re intention is to actually navigate to a different place you can simply have a property on each element of the array called url or source or something similar

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Nike SB x Medicom Dry",
  "description": "Men's T-Shirt",
  "inStock": "$49",
  "image": "../assets/nike_shirt_1.jpg",
  “url”: “<your url here>”
```

}

Then on the html you can have something like

```
<li *ngFor = "let nikeShirt of nikeShirts">
  <img src ={{nikeShirt.image}} height="200" width="250" />
  <h2> {{nikeShirt.name}} </h2>
<p> <i>{{nikeShirt.description}}</i> </p>
<p> {{nikeShirt.inStock}} </p>
  <a href=“{{nikeShirt.url}}” </a>
   <button href="/home" class="btn">Review</button>
</li>
```

By the way your button Review won’t work because buttons don’t have href. They’re not meant not navigate usually. They’re meant for triggering actions.

You can achieve the desired result by converting it to `<a href="/home" class="btn">Review</a>` and style with with some css

Comment: My gosh it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!!! Have been stuck on this for so long

Comment: Always glad to help. Please don’t forget to upvote the answer and mark it as selected  so others can have faster feedback.